# OpenVPN - Fixing DNS leak using UFW

Tags: fedora, iptables, openvpn, network-adapter, ufw

I am currently running OpenVPN on Fedora 24 and experiencing a typical DNS-leakage, since my /etc/resolv.conf entry is not changed after starting OpenVPN.

To get rid of the DNS-leak, I am trying to configure UFW in order to block any other traffic not going through my VPN adapter (tun0 in that case).

UFW status has the following rules:

```
outgoing:               allow from any to any on tun0
ingoing:                allow from any to any on tun0
allow VPN to establish: allow from any to XX.XX.XX.XX
```

After enabling UFW, I can successfully establish a VPN tunnel to the designated address. However, there is no IP-traffic going through tun0 and no internet connection is available to the webbrowser. 
Running TrafShow, I can also see tun0 remains completely silent.

Can anyone help me which point I am still missing in my configuration? Many thanks!